# Python is operator not giving the same result as id function when working with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have always thought that `is` operator is checking whether its operands are stored in the same memory location. If they are, then they must be the same object and if they are not, then they are different objects (possibly with the same value, but that is not what I am interested in).

This has been demonstrated over and over using `id` function which returns an integer representing the unique memory location where the object is stored. This also corresponds to python documentation of `id` function, which states

```
id(obj, /)
    Return the identity of an object.
    
    This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.
    (CPython uses the object's memory address.)
```

In all the examples that I have seen where they were actually using `id` and `is` over the years (quite a bit), if `id`s of two objects were equal then `is` returned `True`. So, somehow I have thought that this always hold.

Here is a quick example using list.

```
c = [[1], [2], [3]]
c[0] = c[1]
```

Now, `c[0]` should point to the same memory location as `c[1]`. If we check the `id`s and compare them with `is` operator, everything looks as expected.

```
c[0] is c[1], id(c[0]) == id(c[1]) , id(c[0]), id(c[1]), type(c[0])
# (True, True, 112392630432, 112392630432, list)
```

If I do a similar thing, but with the numpy array, then the `id`s will be the same, but `is` operator will return `False`

```
c = np.array([1, 2, 3])
c[0] = c[1]
c[0] is c[1], id(c[0]) == id(c[1]) , id(c[0]), id(c[1]), type(c[0])
# (False, True, 112400242960, 112400242960, numpy.int64)
```

Now, `is` is telling me that these two objects are not sitting in the same memory location but `id`s are equal. Even if I construct a list using `numpy.int64` elements (in the first example, I was using list of lists), `is` will return `True`.

```
c = [np.int64(1), np.int64(2), np.int64(3)]
c[0] = c[1]
c[0] is c[1], id(c[0]) == id(c[1]) , id(c[0]), id(c[1]),  type(c[0])
# (True, True, 112277646832, 112277646832, numpy.int64)
```

So my conclusion is that it has something to do with the `numpy.ndarrays` themselves. Later I have found that this is not unique to numpy. If you change `numpy.ndarray` to `torch.Tensor`, then the behavior is the same - `id`s are equal but comparison using `is` operator returns `False`.

Can anyone explain why `a is b` returns `False` while `id(a) == id(b)` returns `True` when working with these numerical libraries?

Comment: Indexing an array doesn't retrieve an object. It *creates* one.

Comment: To quote the quoted documentation: "This is guaranteed to be unique *among simultaneously existing* objects." Whenever ``is`` appears to behave differently than ``id``, that is because ``is`` looks at *two* objects *at once* but ``id`` looks at *one* object  – ``id(a) == id(b)`` looks at *two* objects *one after the other*.

Comment: Object dtype arrays store elements as references to objects with their own `id`, same as `list`. But the numeric dtype arrays don't.  They have their own databuffer with the values stored as bytes.  When you index an array you get a **new** object, array or scalar, that has the same value, but who's `id` has nothing to do with the source array.

Comment: @hpaulj Got it, thanks. That is what I was missing. Just wish the question wasn't closed so quickly pointing to something that doesn't address this at all.